# SSO problem with Azure AD and php web app (Need admin approval - permission error)

Tags: php, azure, single-sign-on

I created web app with Single Sign On (SSO) using Azure AD. I implemented solution with OAuth 2.0.
I tested my solution with my testing Azure AD - its working fine! But when I started using it on my clients Azure AD account I got an error:

> **Need admin approval**
>
> **--Application Name--  needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please, ask an admin to
> grant permission to this app before you can use it.**

I have set API permission for this application in:
**User.Read, email, offline_access, openid,  profile**

But error still the same.
Can somebody help me? What permission do I need to set for my app on my client's Azure AD account?