# Need Admin Approval Azure App with Allow User Consent Enabled

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I've created a web app using asp.net core and I'm trying to authenticate with Azure AD. I've created the app registration and hooked everything up. I'm able to log in fine but when anyone else tries they get the "Need admin approval" message.

My app doesn't require any API permissions and my org has Allow User Consent for Apps enabled. Any ideas on why I would still be getting this error message? I've read all the other posts I could find on this and they didn't seem to be quite the same. This is single tenant only, no api permissions needed.

Here is how I'm setting it up in the web app `services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));`

Edit:
Crap, didn't read them all apparently. Answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70280051/sso-problem-with-azure-ad-and-php-web-app-need-admin-approval-permission-erro) was my issue as well. I had Assignment required enabled, turning it off allowed users to sign in. Is there no way to have users consent and require assignment?

Comment: Please provide us with screenshots of permission in the app and user consent settings .

Answer (score 0):

We can follow the below workaround :-

***We must need global administrator role to turn on the admin consent workflow***

Then Navigate to Enterprise application>User Settings>Admin consent(select yes)> Save.

[image]

---

[image]

For complete setup please refer the below links:-

***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:-*** [***Enable the admin consent workflow***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow#enable-the-admin-consent-workflow)

***BLOG:-*** [***How to grant admin consent to applications in Azure***](https://sharepointstuff.com/2020/12/03/how-to-grant-admin-consent-to-applications-in-azure/)